# How to give an enchanted golden shovel to players without an enchanted golden shovel? (spleef)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently working on implementing a Spleef gamemode into a server I have, and I was wondering how to automatically give players shovels, while also not bombarding them with new shovels. I was hoping that there was a way to give a shovel to players without a shovel already in their inventory through command blocks.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using repeating command blocks (if you can keep a repeating command block running). If you're going to use repeating command blocks that continuously check if a player has the shovel item or not, you'll probably have to turn off CommandBlockOutput. **To turn off the output text that command blocks make, just enter** */gamerule commandBlockOutput false.*

I don't exactly know how to format a command that does something like this, but essentially it needs to **always check if any player has this shovel, and if they don't have this shovel, then give this player 1 of this specific shovel.** I'm pretty sure you can also specify the requirements of what shovel to check and give down to the name (formatting + color), tags, and possibly enchantments (you would need a lot of command formatting, though).

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll experiment and mess around with this to see if I can get it.

Comment: I've done something similar to "checking a player's inventory for a specific item and executing something", although I wrote the command so it actually gave a potion effect. I'm assuming I can reverse the command so it executes only if the inventory does not have the item. 

I'll try and work on tweaking the command and potentially get it working.

Comment: This post answers nothing. You just told the asker to do what they asked about.

Comment: I guess that's true, but I don't exactly have the exact command needed for this procedure. Should I delete the answer?